# how to search a username in php ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, pagination

hey guys I need some help please guide me where I am doing wrong in coding. [This is table of showing record of users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CeFj.png)

I want pagination operation and search operation on my index.php file. Pagination is working but when I am type a single letter (example: a or Haris) on search bar then show me message that data not found [this is message showing when type a username on search bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcIRw.png)

**This my ajax function that on index.php file I am pagination or search**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

         load_data();
         function load_data(query)
        {

           $.ajax({
           url:"search.php",
           method:"POST",
           data:{query:query},
           success:function(data)
        {

           $('#result').html(data);
        }
        });
        }

           $('#message').keyup(function(){
           var srch = $(this).val();
           if(srch != '')
       {

           load_data(srch);
        }

        else
       {
          load_data();
       }
       });


       function load_data(page)  
       {  
       $.ajax({  

            url:"search.php",  
            method:"GET",  
            data:{page:page},  
            success:function(data){  
                 $('#pagination_data').html(data);  
            }  
       })  
  }  

       $(document).on('click', '.pagination_link', function(){  
       var page = $(this).attr("id");  
       load_data(page);  
  });  
  });
  </script>
```

**This my search.php file**

```
<?php
  include("common/config.php");
   $output = '';

    if(isset($_POST["query"]))
   {
    $search =  $_POST["query"];

   $where = "id LIKE '%".$search."%' 
      OR name LIKE '%".$search."%' 
      OR email LIKE '%".$search."%' 
      OR phone LIKE '%".$search."%'";

   $query = $db->select(array("*"),"user","$where","","id desc","");
   }
    else
   {
    $limit = 5; 

    $page = '';
   if (isset($_GET["page"] )) 
      {
    $page  = $_GET["page"]; 
    } 
else 
   {
    $page=1; 
   } 

   $record_index= ($page-1) * $limit; 

    $query = $db->select(array("*"),PREFIX."user", "", "", "id desc", "$record_index, $limit");
    }

  if($query)
 {
    $output .= '
      <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table table bordered">
      <tr>
         <th style="text-align: center !important;"><input type="checkbox" name="select_all" id="select_all" value=""/></th>
         <th style="text-align: center !important;">ID</th>
         <th style="text-align: center !important;">Name</th>
         <th style="text-align: center !important;">Email</th>
         <th style="text-align: center !important;">Phone</th>
         <th colspan="4" style="text-align: center !important;">Action</th>
     </tr>
    ';
      foreach($query as $row)

   {
      $output .= '
    <tr align="center">
      <td align="center"><input type="checkbox"  name="checked_id[]"  
  class="checkbox" value="'.$row->id.'"/></td> 
      <td>'.$row->id.'</td>
      <td>'.$row->name.'</td>
      <td>'.$row->email.'</td>
      <td>'.$row->phone.'</td>
      <td><a href="edit-form.php?edit='.$row->id.'">Edit</a></td>
      <td><a onclick="return confirm(\'Are you sure to delete?\')" 
 href="del.php?del='.$row->id.'">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>';
    }

    $output .= '</table><br /><div align="center">';  
     $total_pages = ceil($db->countfields("*","user") / $limit);  
    for($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++)  
   {  
        $output .= "<span class='pagination_link' style='cursor:pointer; padding:6px; border:1px solid #ccc;' id='".$i."'>".$i."</span>";  
 } 

    $output .= '</div><br /><br />';  
    echo $output;
  }
else
  {
 echo 'Data Not Found';
 }

 ?>
```

**When I am change the name of function,pagination is working but its still search a user record not working.**

```
<script>

   $(document).ready(function(){

   load_data_1();
   load_data_2();

   function load_data_1(query)
    {
      $.ajax({
      url:"search.php",
      method:"POST",
      data:{query:query},
      success:function(data)
    {
      $('#result').html(data);
    }
  });
   }

      $('#message').keyup(function(){
      var srch = $(this).val();
      if(srch != '')
      {
      load_data(srch);
       }
       else
      {
       load_data_1();
      }
       });

       function load_data_2(page)  
  {  
       $.ajax({  
            url:"search.php",  
            method:"GET",  
            data:{page:page},  
            success:function(data){  
                 $('#pagination_data').html(data);  
            }  
       })  
  }  
      $(document).on('click', '.pagination_link', function(){  
       var page = $(this).attr("id");  
       load_data_2(page);  
  });  
});
 </script>
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. Never insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL.

Comment: And can you please format and indent your code properly? It's impossible to see the flow of control clearly with those brackets all over the place. I don't know how people can work efficiently with code laid out like that.

Comment: I am using dbase file that some functions are defined that'why I am using insert query that send directly to sql.

Comment: that still doesn't excuse the complete lack of any validation of the input whatsoever. A user could easily include SQL statements in their search terms that could steal, corrupt or destroy your data

Comment: Anyway there's not enough info. We don't know precisely what SQL statement is formed by your unseen "select" function, or whether you have any data which matches it. You haven't said whether the data is transmitted to the server correctly (have you checked the ajax request in your network tab). There are also two different calls to search.php implemented in your JS, and three different SELECT queries which could be run. You haven't told us specifically which ones of these are being used? It would help to narrow down the problem. What's the flow of control that reproduces the issue?

Comment: It's no good saying " I am type a single letter (example: a or Haris) on search bar " because we can't see your "search bar" and we don't know which piece of Javascript that runs. I'm _guessing_ it maybe triggers the "keyup" event on the "message" element? That's a guess though because an element called "message" doesn't immediately make me think it's a "search" input.

Comment: @ ADyson (This is table of showing record of users)-> please click on this line in above my question then you will see the search bar

Comment: my query is running perfectly but I think that may be I have a issue in my ajax function that written in my index.php file

Comment: Seeing the search bar in a screenshot is nice but it tells me nothing about which code it calls. Your suggestion doesn't answer my questions at all. Please read my comments again properly and answer the questions I asked. If you aren't able to do that, it will be very difficult for me (and probably others) to offer you any meaningful help.

Comment: Actually DanielW below makes a good point, which I hadn't noticed. You can't have 2 functions with the same name within the same scope in JS. The first one can never be used because the second one has already taken its place before you execute it. So chances are you're not calling the bit of PHP code that you thought you were. Again if you'd done some basic debugging as I suggested and checked the actual request being sent (using your browser tools) you might notice which parameter name is being transmitted. If you want to use ajax successfully you need learn to use the debug tools available

Comment: There is no `dataType` in you ajax request

Comment: Robert Rocha I can't understand what you are saying, can you explain it through write a code?

Comment: In your `AJAX` you need to show what type of data you're expecting back from the server with out telling the `JQuery` what type pf data is returning back `JQuery` won't work. Here read [this](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) it'll clear things up for you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see from your code what "PREFIX" is, but in the search query it is missing while it is present in the pagination query. Hope it helps

Comment: No sir prefix is not a issue.

Comment: You have 2 load_data functions, the second function overwrites the first one, so the search is also calling the second function, which is intended to do the pagination. Try to rename your functions to load_data_1 and load_data_2.

Comment: @ Daniel W see my above question I updated it as you said that change the function

Comment: At one place you forget to rename the function: `if(srch != '')
      {
      load_data(srch);
       }`
This should be: 
`if(srch != '')
      {
      load_data_1(srch);
       }`

Comment: Could you please post a screenshot from the inspector's network tab, when you try to do the search? I would like to see the request details which is sent to the server.

Comment: In above my question there is some blue lines please click on it then you will see error message when I am type a letter on search bar

Comment: I've tried the ajax part and if you corrected the function name I've mentioned above, it should work, and it posts the query variable properly. Did you try to run the search query manually from php without the ajax request? Please provide additional details for us to be able to help. (code of the $db->select function, debug output of the variables etc)