# how to retrieve file from database in html tags using php

Tags: php, html

Hey guys I want to retrieve file from database in html tags using php like this

```
<img src="image/<?php echo $fname?>" alt=" " height="75" width="75">
```

This is use for image but I want to use for retrieve file like .doc,.ppt,.pdf,.txt

I am doing like this

```
 <a href="file/<?php echo $filename?>"></a>
```

fetch a file like this

```
$filename = $row['file'];
```

It is better way to retrieve a file of .ppt,.pdf,.txt?

Comment: What file? where is your code ?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming,

- You are not using any frameworks
- Your view files(*.php) and **file** directory in same level.
- $row['file'] contains file name with extension. ex: image1.jpg or
  doc1.xls
- You want to display image in the view file but you want
  to force user to download .doc, .ppt, .pdf (application/octet-stream
  MIME types)

  You can create another php file in same level to force download other extensions. Lets name it download.php

in your view file

```
<?php 
$path = '/file/';
$filePath = $path . $row['file'];
$downloadExtensions = ['doc', 'ppt', 'txt']; // you can add more extensions
?>

<?php if (file_exists($filePath)): ?>
    <?php $extension = pathinfo($filePath, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); ?>


    <?php if (in_array($extension, $downloadExtensions)): ?>
        <a href="download.php?file=<?php echo $row['file']; ?>"><?php echo $row['file']; ?></a>
    <?php else: ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $filePath; ?>"></a>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

in download.php

```
<?php
// download.php
$path = '/file/';
$fileName = $_GET['file'];
$filePath = $path . $fileName;

// verify that the file exists
if (file_exists($filePath) ) {
    // force the download
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" .     basename($fileName) . "\"");
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize($filePath));
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream;");
    readfile($filePath);
}
?>
```

- [MIME types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types)
- [Forcing file downloads in PHP](https://www.abeautifulsite.net/forcing-file-downloads-in-php)
- [PHP pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)
- [PHP filesize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php)
- [PHP in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

Comment: Thanx brother I am already did it... but can you help me on this my question. Please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46303967/how-to-search-a-username-in-php-ajax/46304266?noredirect=1#comment79591927_46304266